# Prime numbers with given difference

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory

Let be given natural numbers N_1,N_2,N_3,...,N_k such that for every prime p less or equal 
k set N_1,N_2,N_3,...,N_k does not contain all reminders modulo p. Is it right that there exists number X such that all X+N_1,X+N_2,X+N_3,...,X+N_k are prime? I think it must follow
from some theorems about prime numbers in arithmetical progression.

Comment: If you could solve the case N_1=1, N_2=3 I'd be very interested ...

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for infinitely many. I can settle your case by exhibiting X=2, can't I?

Comment: Even this variant is not going to work easily: simply look for pairs of consecutive primes arbitrarily far apart from each other to find different twin primes.

Comment: Yes---perhaps one should instead do $N_1=1$, $N_2=3$, $N_3=N+1$ and $N_4=N+3$ for some super-large $N$ congruent to 0 mod 6. This definitely forces infinitely many twin primes.

Answer (score 6):

(This question has been killed in the comments, but it is still lacking the useful pointers.)

This is a weak form of the [Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) which moreover predicts an asymptotic density for the number of such [prime k-tuplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple). Special cases of this include: [twin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), [cousin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_prime), [sexy primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime), [prime quadruplets, quintuplets, and sextuplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_quadruplet). While your conjecture is much weaker than Hardy-Littlewood, Kevin Buzzard's trick in the comments shows that it globally implies the infinitude of prime k-tuplets for any admissible pattern.

As far as I know, the infinitude of prime k-tuplets is an open problem for all fixed admissible patterns with k ≥ 2. Note that the [Green-Tao Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) falls short of proving any instance of this since the step size of the arithmetic progressions is not fixed. (Even the Tao-Ziegler Theorem falls short since the polynomials are required to have vanishing constant term.)

Comment: It has been conjectured that, for any $k>0$ and $n>2$, there are at least as many primes between 2 and $n$ (inclusive) as there are between $k+2$ and $k+n$. About 35 years ago, Hensley and Richards proved that this conjecture is incompatible with the prime $k$-tuples conjecture. It's the only example that comes to my mind of two plausible conjectures being proved incompatible. 

It's generally believed now that prime $k$-tuples is true and the other conjecture is false. 