# Intervals with large numbers of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

This is related to an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17597/prime-numbers-with-given-difference) about [prime k-tuples and constellations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple), but takes a slightly different direction.

Given an integer k, we want to find n such that the interval {n+1, ..., n+k} contains as many primes as possible.  (We consider only n ≥ k to eliminate certain exceptional cases, such as {3,5,7}, which is irregular since for k=5 there can be at most 2 primes in the interval if n>2.)

There is an obvious upper bound a<sub>k</sub> on the number of primes in this interval, given by considering the numbers modulo p for all primes p ≤ k.  More precisely, a<sub>k</sub> is the largest possible cardinality of a set A ⊂ {1, ..., k} such that for some n, the set n+A does not contain any numbers divisible by any prime p ≤ k.

For example, a<sub>3</sub>=2 since out of 3 consecutive numbers at least one is even, and a<sub>7</sub>=3 since out of seven consecutive numbers at least three are even, and at least one of the odd numbers is divisible by 3.  Similarly, a<sub>9</sub>=4 and a<sub>13</sub>=5.

The four bounds listed so far can be achieved by taking n=4, n=10, n=10, n=36, respectively.  The natural question to ask is whether for every k there is a value of n such that the interval {n+1, ..., n+k} contains a<sub>k</sub> primes, but the comments on the [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17597/prime-numbers-with-given-difference) make me suspect that this may be open.  (Another natural question is whether there are infinitely many such n, but since for k=3 this is the twin prime conjecture, that's definitely out of reach at present.)

Since the natural question to ask seems very hard, my question instead is this:  Is anything about the asymptotics of this problem?  More precisely, I'd like to know if something like the following statement is true:  "For every ε>0, there exist infinitely many pairs (k,n) such that the interval {n+1, ..., n+k} contains at least (1-ε)a<sub>k</sub> prime numbers."

There are a few different ways to tweak that statement -- for example, we could ask for infinitely many n for a fixed k, or we could let both k and n become arbitrarily large.  (Of course k will need to become arbitrarily large as ε becomes small.)  I'd be happy with any of them -- I'm asking this question out of curiosity rather than out of a need for a specific result.

Comment: Would Pafnuty Lvovich Chebyshev have related results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fixed $k$ this is definitely hopeless, since it would imply that for some $b$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p + b$ is prime, and this is a well-known open problem that seems out of reach of the latest techniques for finding small gaps between primes (see this survey article of Soundararajan for example: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-01/S0273-0979-06-01142-6/S0273-0979-06-01142-6.pdf)

For similar reasons this will also be hopeless if $k$ is too small depending on $n$.

If $k$ is huge compared with $n$ then the existence of many such pairs would follow immediately from the prime number theorem if only one knew that $a_k \leq (1 + o(1))\pi(k)$. However, I do not believe this is known and in fact I'm nigh-on certain that nothing better than $a_k \leq 2\pi(k)$ is known. This is a result of Montgomery and Vaughan; the slightly weaker bound of $a_k \leq (2 + o(1))\pi(k)$ follows rather easily from the Selberg upper bound sieve. Incidentally, the presence of the factor $2$ here reflects something called the parity problem in sieve theory: breaking it, even by a tiny amount, is generally very problematic.

In the previous discussion referenced above, the result of Hensley and Richards was mentioned. This is an example to show that it is \emph{not} true that $a_k \leq \pi(k)$. As you hint in the question, one might then conjecture that there is $n$ such that $\{n+1,\dots, n+k\}$ contains $a_k > \pi(k)$ primes, in which case one would have a violation of the triangle inequality $\pi(x+y) \leq \pi(x) + \pi(y)$. Such a conjecture would follow from the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture which is, of course, hopelessly out of reach.

Answer (score 1):

OEIS sequence [A120934](http://oeis.org/A120934) gives the least prime $p$ such that the interval $[p,p+\log(p)]$ contains $n$ primes.

Answer (score 0):

For small k, choose n = 1 :-)

Call a finite, non-empty set A of integers ≥ 0 with the smallest element x = 0 a "prime pattern" if for every prime p, there are fewer than p different remainders x % p for integers x in A. For example, { 0, 2 } is a prime pattern. There's the conjecture that for every prime pattern A, there are infinitely many primes p such that p + x is prime for every element x of A. In the case of A = { 0, 2 } that's the twin prime conjecture.

It has been shown that for k ≥ some number around 2,200 it is possible to find a prime pattern A with all elements x ≤ k which has more elements than there are primes in [2, 2 + k). Or more precisely, someone has done an exhaustive search for such prime patterns and found solutions when k ≥ 2,200.

The conjecture says there are infinitely many intervals [p, p + k) containing more primes than the interval [2, 2 + k). Heuristics shows that the numbers p must be *huge*. I'd say there is not a chance in hell to find such an interval, but it's most likely that one exists.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking for a lower bound on $p$ given $k$?

Answer (score -1):

In some sense you're going to want to take n small as the difference between $\pi$(n) and $\pi$(n+k) is going to shrink as n gets large.

I know there are some results where the difference between $\pi$(n) and li(n) is bounded, so combinations of those may give you a bound. Wikipedia (ever reliable source) claims that

|$\pi (n) - li(n) $|$ \le \frac{\sqrt{x}ln(n)}{8\pi}$

is a result of Lowell Schoenfeld.  (it says it assumes the Riemann hypothesis, so take it or leave it as you will) but then you could bound $\pi(n+k) - \pi(n)$. I don't know how well this works